# Guidance on migrating a .NET windows forms application to a web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, migration, winforms-to-web

Are there any good books or websites on this subject covering subjects like:

- different migration scenario's (big bang, module for module, function for function) pros and cons
- do's en dont's
- tooling
- handling customer expectations

We have a rather large winforms based product which we would like to migrate to the web. Migrating in a 'big bang' scenario would probably take at least two years. We're looking for alternative scenario's.
I'm especially looking for ways to handle the inbetween scenario, what options do you have to keep customers happy.

- Let them use the windows application at the same time as the new web
  application?
- Let the windows application use the new features from the web
  application via a service interface?
- Accept the cost of double maitenance for a while to keep customers happy?

Comment: Actually is not migrating but a new project that you get from the one to the other the program logic. Every dialog on one program must be web page to the other. But here the web is not keep the parametres as the program keep, so must think and redesign the ui. (the 2 years is very optimistic for a large product that you build for years). Better think is as a new product and start from the basic.

Comment: Depends absolutely entirely on how the forms app was written.  Either way, not a coding question and better suited to 'programmers' I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on our own experience with moving applications from desktop to web: carefuly inspect the architecture of your winforms applications and **if** possible - try to provide a web interface at the service or persistence level so that your windows applications use web services instead of directly talking to the database. Then you can let your users launch desktop modules from the application server using clickonce.

Such approach let us move to web quickly and users got the same GUI and a new way to access the application. In fact, it took like 3 or 4 months to redesign existing applications so that they use web services.

Then, we were replacing modules one by one, implementing them as web applications and maintaining both (clickonce and web) for a short period of time so that users were able to get used to new modules.

The migration of consecutive modules from clickonce to web was prioritized in an obvious way - we've started from modules that were used by most users. In fact, the initial release of the system has only one web forms module ready and remaining modules are being replaced for over 2 years now, one by one.

Comment: wiktor- +1. however, in my experience, you have to be very careful in how you implement the webservice layer (i.e. authentication/persistance) as you can create a huge bottleneck just checking the validity of each request. examine very closely what you consider 'public' api vs authenticated api - the approach and payoff are very different

Comment: Absolutely agree. Adding a third layer to a windows forms application has to be done carefully because of possible performance and security issues. However, most probably it's still much faster than totally rewriting whole stuff from scratch. And time is money.

Answer (score 5):

You are more likely be doing a complete rewrite.  Because web is conceptually different from windows forms, there would be a lot of changes.

Your best bet is stop new development on windows forms app.  Start writing a new app for the new features. Then start moving one isolated feature at a time to web.

**You have two options for the UI**

1. webforms - matches closely with windows forms model.  If you are
   using any 3rd party controls like devexpress, you can find the
   equivalents in webforms.
2. mvc - It is more like re-architecting the whole presentation layer. 
       If your UI layer is already separated from business layer, then it
       would be a good choice to go down the path of MVC.  However the
       development experience is totally different from doing windows
       forms.

**State**

- Maintaining application state is comparatively simple in windows
     forms.  In webforms you have viewstate to do that for you.  But you are going to run in to rude shocks as you run into limitations of viewstate, especially when it gets too large.
- In MVC, you are completely responsible for maintaining the state.

**New skills**

You require new skills to mimic state-full scenarios

- Strong understanding of javascript, ajax, at least one javascript
  framework like jquery.  3rd party commercial tool kits can ease some
  of these pains.
- Depending on complexity you might need web application frameworks
  like Backbone.js /Knockout

**Expectations**

It would be very expensive to achieve the same responsiveness as windows app, as you will be messing with multiple technologies.  Probably your users are going to hate the new app initially.  Having skilled web designers on staff is very important

Comment: I agree that rewriting a big part of the application is probably required. I'm looking for a way to bridge the time.

Comment: You also need to consider, what if the conversion project is abandoned in the middle? Thinking about the project in the lines of 'let us make these x number of features available on the web in phase 1', is a pragmatic approach.